# How can I stop JavaScript from passing a class by reference?

Tags: javascript, typescript, pass-by-reference

I have the following code in the constructor of a class (shortened for the purpose of the question):

```
constructor(effect: EffectInstance, names: string[], count?: number) {
    this.effect = effect; // instance of a class "Effect"
    let name; for (name of names) {
        this.custom.set(name, this.effect); // custom: Map
    }
}
```

> *`EffectInstance` is the type of this class, which is generic*

When I change `this.effect.name` in  a method of the class, or when I grab the effect from the Map `this.custom` and change its name, both are changed.

From what I can tell, this is due to JavaScript's pass-by-reference behavior with objects, as I'm 100% certain that I'm not modifying the values I don't want modified. (I'd like to be able to rename the Effect instance in the `custom` Map, but keep `this.effect.name` unchanged)

I tried to re-instantiate the classes with the parameters in `constructor()`, but this raises a new issue: I'd be losing types, and I can't seem to figure out how to work around this. Here's what I tried:

(`EffectInstance`, for reference: `<EffectInstance extends Effect>`)

```
constructor(effect: EffectInstance, names: string[], count?: number) {
    this.effect = effect;
    let altEffect = effect instanceof PlayerEffect ? new PlayerEffect(effect.name, effect.ignoreRaces) : new Effect(effect.name);
    let name; for (name of names) {
        this.custom.set(name, altEffect);
    }
}
```

Doing so, TS raises this error on `altEffect`:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'Effect' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EffectInstance'.   'Effect' is assignable to the constraint of type 'EffectInstance', but 'EffectInstance' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Effect'.
```

I need to either stop the pass-by-reference behavior or preserve the type that EffectInstance contains. How can I do this?

Comment: You can’t change pass by reference behavior - that is integral to how JavaScript works. As you’ve noticed the `effect` you pass in is the one and only instance that is both this.effect and the values in the map.

Comment: @Joe I'm not trying to change the behavior; I'm trying to work around it or prevent it. Sorry if the wording was wrong

Comment: I would be considering how to decouple the name from the effect since you want to reuse the effect instance. How about a wrapper object that you instantiate in your loop that shadows Effect and allows a name override?

Comment: @Joe The goal is for `this.effect` to be a separate instance of the effect that retains its default state, while the instances in the Map are intended to be modified individually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most languages pass objects by reference, so this is not a unique behavior with javascript.

If you want to pass a copy of the class instance and not the original instance and send the clone where you don't want send the original instance.

```js
class Car {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

let orignalClass = new Car('BMW');

let cloneClass = Object.assign(Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(orignalClass)), orignalClass)

console.log(orignalClass);
console.log(cloneClass);

// now both can be updated individually
orignalClass.name = 'BMw-1';
cloneClass.name = "BMW-copy"

console.log("after update");
console.log(orignalClass);
console.log(cloneClass);
```

Comment: You can’t clone class instances like this

Comment: The goal is to keep the class instantiated, and preserve types. IIRC, it's not recommended to try to json-ify classes/functions

Answer (score 0):

through your code, this.custom type should be Effect.

```
constructor(effect: EffectInstance, names: string[], count?: number) {
    this.custom = new Map<string, Effect>(); // altEffect type could be PlayerEffect or Effect
    this.effect = effect;
    let altEffect = effect instanceof PlayerEffect ? new PlayerEffect(effect.name, effect.ignoreRaces) : new Effect(effect.name);
    let name; for (name of names) {
        this.custom.set(name, altEffect);
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, as the generic (`EffectInstance`) is necessary to pass the specific Effect extension class down to the Map, that way typings stay consistent

Comment: But your code makes the altEffect may be an Effect, not always a PlayerEffect.

Comment: since Effect passes the filter of `EffectInstance extends Effect`, I don't see what the issue is.   EffectInstance holds the type passed in to the generic class, so while effect could be either Effect or PlayerEffect, it will always be the same as the rest of the effect types throughout the class instance. could you perhaps explain a little more?